# Kong route using POST changes request's Content-Type

Tags: javascript, kong

Trying to access a NestJS application through Kong, the application's route expect a POST request with a `application/josn` content type, however Kong replaces that value for `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.

Why?

The Request:

```
fetch(`${API_URL}${MESSAGE_API_PATH}`, {
  method: "POST",
  mode: "no-cors",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    Accept: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    foo: "Hello world"
  }),
})
```

The server receives the headers:

```
...
accept: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
...
```

I cannot understand why Kong would replace the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Please share the exact Kong configuration  in use - ie, routes / services / plugins with the exact steps you took to reproduce the issue.